# Etemadi's $L^1$ Strong law of large numbers fails without assuming identically distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Problem:** Construct a sequence $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of nonnegative independent random variables with $E[X_n]=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}n=\infty\quad\text{almost surely.}$$
This would give a counterexample to Etemadis's Strong Law of Large Numbers presented in Durrett's Probability Theory and Examples.

---

I cannot seem to come up with anything that makes sense for this problem. Does anybody have a hint on how to get started?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: To clarify:  There is nothing wrong with Etemadi's theorem and proof.  It requires the identically distributed assumption.  To show an example of what can go wrong without that assumption, you will want variables $X_i$ to have variances that increase to infinity with $i$.  To keep your example as simple as possible, you might consider 2-valued random variables.

Comment: @Michael I think the OP didn't say that the proof is wrong and he is looking for a particular example.

Comment: @user119016 : Actually the OP asked "Does anybody have a hint on how to get started?" So the OP is not asking for a particular example (which would be a full solution to the problem).  I have given a directed hint. I wanted to emphasize nothing is wrong with Etemadi's proof because of the sentence "This would give a counterexample to Etemadi's Strong Law of Large Numbers" which might be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @Michael, Etemadi's theorem assumes the variables are identically distributed, so the question is to show this assumption cannot be dropped. Suppose that for $k \ge 1$, the independent variables $Y_k$ take the values $0,1$, with $P(Y_k=1)=(k\log(1+ k))^{-1}$.
Let $X_k=k\log(1+ k) Y_k$. By the Borel-Cantelli lemma, the event $Y_k=1$ happens infinitely often almost surely.
For each $k$ such that $Y_k=1$ we have $X_k/k=\log(1+k)$, so the limsup mentioned in the original problem is indeed $\infty$ with probability 1.